# Katekyo Hitman Reborn crossover with Nurarihyon

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, crossovers, katekyo-hitman-reborn, nurarihyon-no-mago

I'm looking for a fanfiction where Tsuna is a girl who was unsealed by an omyoji from *Nurarihyon*. She fights yokai including her guardians, she hates her family Nana and Iemitsu and threw Reborn into a river when he told her he was there to train her. Does anybody know what this fanfiction is called?

Fem Tsuna is a human who is trained to be an Onmyoji by Hidemoto Keikain, who saved her from being bullied. He unsealed her when he sensed she was sealed. She hates Nana for not caring for her and lemitsu and the Ninth for sealing her. She throws Reborn into a river when he comes to train her. Her guardians and her are trained to fight yokai which in turn they help Rikuo fight Abe no Seimei. They sabotage his birth from Hagoromo Gitsune by purifying the water she lies in. They end up watching from the sideline when Rikuo confronts Abe no Seimei.

Comment: Ah, *Katekyo Hitman Reborn*?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe *[Yokai Blood](https://m.fanfiction.net/s/9089793/1/Yokai-Blood)*?

> Tsuna and her mother have a secret not even Iemitsu knows about, something they planned to keep a secret until they died. When Yuki-Onna calls for help, Tsuna and her mother are thorn between helping their family and exposing themselves or remain silence and see how their family starts to disappear one by one right in front of their eyes... YokaiFemTsuna x All,

Comment: I actually already read that one. The one I'm looking for I read it a long time ago I'm not sure if the writer pulled it down or put it on a different site but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you clarify which parts don't match? That may help us narrow down the ones that do.

Comment: Fem tsuna is human who is trained to be an onmyoji by hidemoto keikain who saved her from being bullied. He unsealed her when he sensed she was sealed. She hates Nana for not caring for her and lemitsu and the ninth for sealing her. She throws reborn into a river when he comes to train her. Her guardians and her are trained to fight yokai which in turn they help rikuo fight abe no seimei. They sabotage his birth from hagoromo gitsune by purifying the water she lays. They end up watching from the side line when rikuo confronts abe no seimei.